# How to remove public visiblity of a google spreadsheet by script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to remove the public visibility of a file using a script.
Is that possible?
Pupose: I would like to find all spreadsheets in a folder and remove the 'Public' property, so the URL cannot be accessed by anyone having the link. Only the editors/viewers of the file should have access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

The [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) can set specific permissions for files under a specific MIME type, you can use this code to remove public access and restore the permission setting to `Restricted`, which is the default:

```
function permissions() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder-id-here");
  var files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    filePermission = files.next().setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE)
                                 .setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

The folder ID can be found in the link, i.e, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/(folder ID). `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` is the MIME type for Google Sheets files.

### References:

[setSharing()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype,-permissiontype)

[enum Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)

[enum Permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)